# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - running a java file with external libraries

Tags: java, classpath

I am new to java and have used it in netBeans but have never tried to compile or run it from terminal. So, my question may look naive. I have a directory of this structure:

`Folder X` contains:
couple of files and a folder named `esa-lucene`.

`esa-lucene` is a directory having three folders `src, lib, web`:

```
.classpath, lib, .project, .settings, src, web
```

and I am trying to run a java file " `ESAWikipediaIndexer.java`" which exists in this subdirectory:

```
X/esa-lucene/src/edu/wiki/index/ESAWikipediaIndexer.java
```

I cd into `Folder X` and use this:

```
java -cp esa-lucene.jar edu.wiki.index.ESAWikipediaIndexer
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/wiki/index/ESAWikipediaIndexer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.wiki.index.ESAWikipediaIndexer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: edu.wiki.index.ESAWikipediaIndexer. Program will exit.
```

also I've checked .classpath and it contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/servlet-api.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="web/WEB-INF/lib/lucene-analyzers-3.0.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="web/WEB-INF/lib/lucene-core-3.0.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="web/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="web/WEB-INF/lib/trove-2.1.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

I've checked the `lib` and `web/WEB-INF/lib/` folders as well and all the required external libraries (jar files) also exist in this folder.

I searched to find any solution and tried a couple of things but none of them worked. Have no clue how to make it work!

BTW, apparently people have used this package before, and I just downloaded to use it too but wasn't successful so far.

Comment: have you tried : java -cp esa-lucene.jar:.

Comment: I just tried java -cp esa-lucene.jar:. edu.wiki.index.ESAWikipediaIndexer and it gives me the same error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053146/set-folder-for-classpath-in-java

Comment: @Alvin - If I understand the NoClassDefFoundError correctly, I don't think that the problem is about finding external libraries. I guess, I am not calling the mentioned java file properly.

Comment: Yeah, 9 times out of 10 (of not 10 of 10), NoClassDefFoundError indicates some sort of problem with your jar search path.  This can either be a class missing altogether, or a version mismatch of some sort.  In this case it looks like a class is just plain missing (though sometimes "ClassNotFoundException" can be deceptive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are referring to Eclipse classpath and .project files. That being the case why dont you try running it in eclipse.

However since here you are running it manually the classpath entries in classpath file are not being used. Also can you tell us where the .class file for the ESAWikipediaIndexer.java. If you run the below command

> java -cp */esa-lucene.jar edu.wiki.index.ESAWikipediaIndexer

From the directory where it is located, it should work. 
Also you need to provide full path or relative path to esa-lucene.jar in the above command.

Comment: When I try to compile ESAWikipediaIndexer manually it gives me this error: ESAWikipediaIndexer.java:114: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WikipediaAnalyzer
location: class edu.wiki.index.ESAWikipediaIndexer
     writer = new IndexWriter(indexDir, new WikipediaAnalyzer(), true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED); 
Note: ESAWikipediaIndexer.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: is there a bin directory that is being automatically created by eclipse ?

Comment: no. the esa-lucene that I downloaded in detail is available here: https://github.com/faraday/wikiprep-esa/tree/master/esa-lucene

Comment: Try importing your downloaded code basee into eclipse as File->import->Existing projects into workspace. And rpovide the top level directory of your downloaded code. It should work for you.

Comment: I used netBeans and imported it as eclipse project and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you need to make sure the ESAWikipediaIndexer.class file is either in the esa-lucene.jar or in a edu/wiki/index folder structure locatable in the directory you run the java command from. Here's what you can do. look in the jar file to make sure the edu/wiki/index folder structure exists in it. You can use jar -tvf esa-lucene.jar or if you are on windows copy esa-lucene.jar to esa-lucene.zip and double click it to open it up. If that's not where your ESAWikipediaIndexer.class is then it's probably under either the bin, build, classes, or target folder from your project's root. Many IDEs output to something like build/classes. If the class output is there then add build/classes to your classpath in your above command like: java -cp build/classes:esa-lucene.jar edu.wiki.index.ESAWikipediaIndexer on Mac/Linux or java -cp build/classes;esa-lucene.jar edu.wiki.index.ESAWikipediaIndexer on Windows.