# java import static org.mockito not working

Tags: java, import, mockito

I downloaded the `mockito-all-1.9.5.jar` and put it in `~/java`. Then I set the classpath -

```
export CLASSPATH=~/java
```

I am getting this error -

```
a.java:3: package org does not exist
import static org.mockito.*;
```

Any ideas what can be the cause?

Comment: possible duplicate of [set folder for classpath in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053146/set-folder-for-classpath-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the jar to your classpath:

```
export CLASSPATH=~/java/mockito-all-1.9.5.jar
```

The class files are not in your `~/java` but in the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to put the library in your classpath ?

If there is no special reason, the good way to add a jar is to put the jar in your project, then from eclispe, click right on the jar and click on buildPath->Add to build path.