# Java compile class dependent on two jars and one separate class

Tags: java, servlets, jar, javac

I'm having problems compiling my servlet. I have searched around a lot, but none show how to compile with both jars AND class dependencies, just either or.

I have two jars: `SQLite` and `Servlet`. However I have managed to compile `SQLServer` with the `SQLite` jar.

So my problem is to compile `RegisterServlet`, which is dependent on both `servlet-api.jar` and the compiled `SQLServer.class`.

If anything is unclear, please comment.

What I'm after is something like this:

`javac -cp servlet.jar; SQLite.class RegisterServlet.java`

[image]

Comment: Put the jar file on the `java` CLASSPATH. And the appropriate directory for the root of your package tree.

Comment: The classpath is the classpath, it doesn't matter if elements on the path are java files or directories with class files.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try universal solution for building Java applications - [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). This tool handles the following for you:

- Managing the dependencies and downloading neccesary jars. For your case, this is going to be `servlet-api` and `sqlite-jdbc`.
- Handling `classpath` for you - for 95% cases you won't need to worry about it anymore;
- Compiling your application;
- Packaging it to whatever form you need - `jar`, `war`, `ear` or something exotical by custom plugins.

Comment: Thank you, yes I know, I'm going to learn it. But the thing is I just want to get my server running tonight, without having to learn ant/maven/*

Comment: @Jakkra Then I think you need to compile `RegisterServlet` adding both `servlet-api.jar` and `SqlServer.class` to the classpath as commented under the question.

Comment: Ant is quite easy to learn, and your chances are much higher to get your server running tonight if you copy/paste the compile examples from their docs.

Comment: @ Alexey Yah, the thing is I can't figure out how to do that ;)

Comment: @Jakkra http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053146/set-folder-for-classpath-in-java - try this. I think the way described there handles both jars and .class-es.

Comment: Can't get it to work. When I try to do like them, I still get error.

Comment: @Jakkra Consider adding the catalog tree structure with information on where each of the discussed files located.

Comment: Well, to make it easier to compile I just put all files in the same folder.

Comment: @Jakkra I assume your packages are correct, then you should use `javac -cp . RegisterServlet.java`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52448/discussion-between-jakkra-and-alexey-malev)