# How do I link my res folder to my java project

Tags: java, file-io

I just started a new Java Project and I'm working on Animations atm, my question now is how do I link my res source folder with the project so that I can read images via

```
img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name));
```

from that folder? Normally I they can only be read when they are in the

Comment: Add the folder to the classpath or let your build process put the content into the jar(s).

Comment: how do I add this folder to my classpath?

Comment: That depends on how you're starting the application. If you're using the command line, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053146/set-folder-for-classpath-in-java

Comment: I'm not running it from the command line but I found it now, THX nevertheless :D

Answer (score 0):

*if we assume that your resource folder is called "resources":*

```
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(yourclassName.class.getResource("/resources/..."));
```