# Why can't the Compiler locate external libraries in my Java program?

Tags: java, macos, jodatime, javac

I've created a Java program which uses the JodaTime library, and I'm trying to compile the program within the Mac console, but when I do I get the following error:

> error: package org.joda.time does not exist

I tried setting the class path in my .bashrc profile as follows:

> export CLASSPATH="/Users/myname/Java
>   Libraries/joda-time:$CLASSPATH"

But I still get the same error when I try to compile.

I configured the Joda-Time library to my build path in Eclipse, and the program runs as expected in the IDE, so this tells me that it definitely has the classes I need for my program.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: try printing the value of CLASSPATH. It might clarify the problem

Comment: show the content of `/Users/myname/Java Libraries/joda-time`

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053146/set-folder-for-classpath