# ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl

Tags: spring, ignite

I have tried to run Apache Ignore on Windows 10 Professional. I've run example-cache example in ignite directory as follows:

```
D:\work\tools\apache ignite 1.9.0\apache-ignite-fabric-1.9.0-bin>bin\ignite.bat examples\config\example-cache.xml
```

I've previously set IGNITE_HOME environment variable to

```
D:\work\tools\apache ignite 1.9.0\apache-ignite-fabric-1.9.0-bin
```

But I have this exception stack:

```
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to create Ignite component (consider adding ignite-spring module to classpath) [component=SPRING, cls=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:946)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:350)
        at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:302)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to create Ignite component (consider adding ignite-spring module to classpath) [component=SPRING, cls=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComponentType.componentException(IgniteComponentType.java:320)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComponentType.create0(IgniteComponentType.java:296)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComponentType.create(IgniteComponentType.java:207)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.loadConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:637)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:840)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:749)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:619)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:589)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:347)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComponentType.create0(IgniteComponentType.java:282)
        ... 8 more
Failed to start grid: Failed to create Ignite component (consider adding ignite-spring module to classpath) [component=SPRING, cls=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl]
Note! You may use 'USER_LIBS' environment variable to specify your classpath.
```

I've tried to set IGNITE_HOME to `D:\work\tools\apache ignite 1.9.0\apache-ignite-fabric-1.9.0-bin\libs` which contains the jar file `ignite-spring-1.9.0.jar` containing the class `org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set IGNITE_HOME to "D:\work\tools\apache ignite 1.9.0\apache-ignite-fabric-1.9.0-bin".

Or USER_LIBS to "D:\work\tools\apache ignite 1.9.0\apache-ignite-fabric-1.9.0-bin\libs" as it was suggested.

Comment: Try to unset `IGNITE_HOME` (i.e. set to empty string). I would also try to remove directory with spaces in the name. It can probably cause troubles.

Comment: I'mm will try that on tuesday when I go to office. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

I am just setting up Ignite and had exactly the same problem (I am in Ignite version 2.6 though).

I think I found a simple solution after debugging the shell scripts in $IGNITE_HOME/bin, particularly $IGNITE_HOME/bin/include/setenv.sh

The fix is to replace this line form setenv.sh:

IGNITE_LIBS="${IGNITE_HOME}/libs/*"

by this other line instead:

IGNITE_LIBS="${IGNITE_HOME}/libs/*;${IGNITE_HOME}/libs/ignite-spring/*"

The reason this works IMHO is that IGNITE_LIBS is how the classpath is set in $IGNITE_HOME/bin/ignite.sh, in the line

CP="${IGNITE_LIBS}"

($CP is later used as the class path in a Java -cp $CP call).

And since the classpath wildcards are not recursive (see e.g. [Set folder for classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053146/set-folder-for-classpath)), there is basically a bug in the distribution because a classpath of $IGNITE_HOME/libs/* will never find $IGNITE_HOME/libs/ignite-spring/ignite-spring-2.6.0.jar which is the jar you need, I believe.