# ImageIO.read getResource error

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I am experiencing a strange problem. Here is my snippet of code:

```
...
public xProgressBar(xTheme theme) {
    try {
      this.update = ImageIO.read(xTheme.class.getResource("/images/" + xThemeSettings.PROGRESSBAR_IMAGES[0]));
    }
...
```

And when I run a program, I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
```

Here is a file structure:

[image]

As you can see, the `res` folder is at the root with the `src` folder. I have read a lot of similar questions, but nothing helped.

Comment: Why do you thing that `xTheme.class.getResource()` should find the resources under `res/`? What makes you think that could possibly work?

Comment: Well, I also tried to add res to the path, but that doesn't work..

Comment: res/images, /res/images, ./res/images. None of this works.

Comment: You're not answering my question. You're using a method named getResource(), on the type java.lang.Class. Why don't you read its javadoc to know what it does and how it works, instead of trying random things? Hint: it delegates to the ClassLoader to load resources. The ClassLoader doesn't load resources from arbitrary locations, magically. It finds resources from jars and directories that are in the runtime classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `getResource` to find a file, the corresponding folder (`res` in this case) needs to be in the `classpath`. If it's not in the classpath, `InputStream` returned by `getResource` will always be `null`.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053146/set-folder-for-classpath) how to add folder(s) into `classpath`.

Answer (score 0):

Your call `.getResource("/images/...")` didn't succeed and it returned `null`. Hence you were calling `ImageIO.read(null)` and got a `IllegalArgumentException`.

For your resources located in the `res` folder to be found
by `...getResource(...)`, you need to make `res` a source folder of your Eclipse project.
To achieve this: Right-click on your `res` folder, in the popup-menu select
`Build path` -> `Use as Source Folder`.

[image: screenshot]

You will notice then

- `res` will appear with the same icon as your `src` folder.
- `res` will be added to the `.classpath` file of your project.